# Why does a browser ask for camera permission when camera web app is in an iframe, but otherwise just works without asking permission?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, webcam

I have a simple web app (built in Google apps script) that is using the webcam.  When I run it directly from the app url, then the camera just works, but if I embed the app in an iframe with allow="autoplay; camera" then the camera will only work after clicking 'Allow' to the browser pop out: This file wants to use your camera 'Allow' or 'Block'.  The browser is set to allow camera by default in the browser settings.  Does anyone know why this is?